# Get started with shadowrun as GM (lore and books)

Tags: lore, shadowrun

Some friends of mine really like shadowrun and I would like to start a new group with them as a GM (probably Shadowrun 5).

Now I am very much new to shadowrun as the setting and while I have heard of it and played a little bit of one of the PC-Games I am looking for a list of novels that I could read to get to know the world and its major players.

Also a recommendation of a good adventure to start would be great!

Also should I go for the base version or are there some interesting "add ons" for the core book that I should look into?

Thanks!

Comment: I am confused, my question is pretty much exactly this :
https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45785/what-book-can-i-read-to-familiarize-myself-with-dd-5es-world-and-lore?rq=1
Should I just paraphrase that question exactly?

Comment: The policies of the stack have changed over time. The question you linked is three years old and predates the metatopic SSD linked where it was announced that recommendation requests were off-topic for the stack. It would have been an acceptable question once, but now you'll have to take it elsewhere.

Comment: Makes sense should I delete the question?

Comment: @Gravetow not necessarily... you could salvage it, if you describe us what you seek more. Your "I want to leanr about the world" question could be turned into "Where do I find information about Seattle in 2073 and the companies in it?" would be not a shopping question. Howeger: SR is playable with Core-Book-Only since the Aniversary core book, and 5 makes it pretty decent again.

Comment: @trish don't answer in comments... Gravetow: you  don't need to delete. questions without activity just sink down when more are asked/answered.

Comment: You can ask anything about shadowrun, just not "what book...".

Comment: Several of the highest Shadowrun questions are closed, and some of them are variations of this question. rpg.stackexchange comes across as a poor or unpopular place to ask Shadowrun questions.

Comment: pity, but mcv seems to be right :( - while I agree that a bit of effort should go into your questions, out of respect for readers, some of the rules which wording of the same meaning is acceptable and which is not seem arbitrary, and are non-obvious especially to newbies.